# Bug no código de consulta Spring com Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

Estou com um problema, estou estudando spring mvc com hibernate e acabei entrando em um bug onde ele retorna a seguinte exceção "java.lang.NullPointerException", segue os códigos:

**ContactController**

```
package br.com.agenda.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import br.com.agenda.services.ContactService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/contact")
public class ContactController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView listContact() {
        ContactService contactService = new ContactService();
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("contacts");
        modelAndView.addObject("contacts", contactService.listAll());
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

**IContactService**

```
package br.com.agenda.interfaces;

import java.util.List;
import br.com.agenda.models.Contact;

public interface IContactService {

    public void save(Contact contact);

    public Contact searchId(Integer id);

    public List<Contact> listAll();

    public List<Contact> listSpecific(String field, String value);
}
```

**ContactService**

```
package br.com.agenda.services;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import br.com.agenda.daos.ContactDAO;
import br.com.agenda.interfaces.IContactService;
import br.com.agenda.models.Contact;

public class ContactService implements IContactService {

    @Autowired
    private ContactDAO contactDAO = new ContactDAO();

    public void save(Contact contact) {
        contactDAO.save(contact);
    }

    public Contact searchId(Integer id) {
        return contactDAO.search(id);
    }

    public List<Contact> listAll() {
        return contactDAO.listAll();
    }

    public List<Contact> listSpecific(String field, String value) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**ContactDAO**

```
package br.com.agenda.daos;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceException;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import br.com.agenda.models.Contact;

@Repository
public class ContactDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager manager;

    public void save(Contact contact) {
        try {
            if (contact.getId() != null) {
                manager.persist(contact);
            } else {
                manager.merge(contact);
            }
        } catch(RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public Contact search(Integer id) {
        try {
            return manager.find(Contact.class, id);
        } catch(RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    public List<Contact> listAll() {
        try {
            return manager
                .createQuery("select distinct(c) from tblContacts c join fetch c.phones", Contact.class)
                .getResultList();
        } catch(PersistenceException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Contact**

```
package br.com.agenda.models;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

import br.com.agenda.models.Phone;

@Entity
@Table(name="tblContacts")
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="idContacts")
    private Integer id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name="nameContacts")
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name="emailContacts")
    private String email;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<Phone> phones;

    public void addPhone(Phone phone) {
        phones.add(phone);
    }

    public List<Phone> getPhones() {
        return phones;
    }

    public void setPhones(List<Phone> phones) {
        this.phones = phones;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

**Phone**

```
package br.com.agenda.models;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tblPhones")
@Embeddable
public class Phone {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="idPhones")
    private Integer id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name="dddPhones")
    private Integer ddd;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name="numberPhones")
    private Integer number;

    public Integer getDdd() {
        return ddd;
    }

    public void setDdd(Integer ddd) {
        this.ddd = ddd;
    }

    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }       
}
```

Pilha de Erros

```
type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    br.com.agenda.daos.ContactDAO.listAll(ContactDAO.java:52)
    br.com.agenda.services.ContactService.listAll(ContactService.java:23)
    br.com.agenda.controllers.ContactController.listContact(ContactController.java:19)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.5.11 logs.
```

-- Arquivos de Configuração --

AppWebConfiguration

```
package br.com.agenda.conf;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import br.com.agenda.controllers.IndexController;
import br.com.agenda.daos.ContactDAO;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses={IndexController.class, ContactDAO.class})
public class AppWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    //Configurado pasta raiz das viewers e o suffix .jsp para as mesmas que serão carregadas
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {  
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

JPAConfiguration

```
package br.com.agenda.conf;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JPAConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory()
    {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());

        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"br.com.agenda.models"});
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;

    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/agenda");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("");

        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties additionalProperties()
    {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager (EntityManagerFactory emf)
    {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

ServletSpringMVC

```
package br.com.agenda.conf;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class ServletSpringMVC extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() 
    {
        return null;
    }

    //definido de onde vira as cofiguracoes para rodar as classes
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{AppWebConfiguration.class, JPAConfiguration.class};
    }

    //indica a pasta raiz mappeando o servlet
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() 
    {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
}
```

Me ajudem e/ou realizem as correções por favor, desde ja agradeço.

Comment: Edite a pergunta e adicione a pilha de erros tambem.

Comment: Foi editado @diegofm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NullPointerException` está ocorrendo porque você está instanciando manualmente as classes `ContactService` e `ContactDAO`, dessa forma o Spring não injeta o `EntityManager`.

Mude esses trechos do código para:

ContactService:

```
@Service
public class ContactService implements IContactService {

    @Autowired
    private ContactDAO contactDAO;

    //os seus métodos
}
```

ContactController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/contact")
public class ContactController {

    @Autowired
    private IContactService contactService;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView listContact() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("contacts");
        modelAndView.addObject("contacts", contactService.listAll());
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

### Edição:

Segue abaixo o código completo que funcionou comigo sem lançar nenhuma exceção. Caso você ainda venha a enfrentar alguma exceção, é provável que essa exceção seja diferente da que está na sua pergunta e seja causada por alguma outra classe que não nos foi listada.

Dessa forma, se uma exceção for lançada, sugiro que você crie outro projeto com os arquivos que colocarei abaixo e, aos poucos, vá adicionando as classes/funcionalidades restantes para descobrir onde está o problema. Se surgir alguma dúvida, pode perguntar.

#### pom.xml

Eu uso o maven para gerenciar minhas dependências, caso você utilize outro gerenciador ou precise adicionar/substituir dependências, ajuste de acordo com suas necessidades.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                            http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com.agenda</groupId>
    <artifactId>agenda</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>agenda</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <log4j2.version>2.7</log4j2.version>
        <org.springframework.version>4.3.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.39</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>agenda</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

#### AppWebConfiguration.java

```
package br.com.agenda.conf;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"br.com.agenda"})
public class AppWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {  
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

#### JPAConfiguration.java

Não se esqueça de adicionar o nome de usuário e senha do seu banco de dados.

```
package br.com.agenda.conf;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JPAConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());

        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"br.com.agenda.models"});
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;

    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/agenda?useSSL=false");
        dataSource.setUsername("");
        dataSource.setPassword("");

        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager (EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

#### ServletSpringMVC.java

```
package br.com.agenda.conf;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class ServletSpringMVC extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{AppWebConfiguration.class, JPAConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
}
```

#### ContactDAO.java

Mudei o `ContactDAO` para uma interface e criei uma implementação chamada `JPAContactDAO`:

```
package br.com.agenda.daos;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import br.com.agenda.models.Contact;

public interface ContactDAO {

    public void save(Contact contact);

    public Contact update(Contact contact);

    public void remove(Contact contact);

    public Optional<Contact> find(int identifier);

    public List<Contact> listAll();
}
```

#### JPAContactDAO.java

```
package br.com.agenda.daos;

import static java.util.Objects.requireNonNull;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import br.com.agenda.models.Contact;

@Repository
public final class JPAContactDAO implements ContactDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager manager;

    @Override
    public void save(Contact contact) {
        requireNonNull(contact, "contact cannot be null");
        manager.persist(contact);
    }

    @Override
    public Contact update(Contact contact) {
        requireNonNull(contact, "contact cannot be null");
        return manager.merge(contact);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(Contact contact) {
        requireNonNull(contact, "contact cannot be null");
        manager.remove(contact);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Contact> find(int identifier) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(manager.find(Contact.class, identifier));
    }

    @Override
    public List<Contact> listAll() {
        return manager.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT(c) FROM Contact c JOIN FETCH c.phones", Contact.class)
                    .getResultList();
    }
}
```

### ContactService.java

Mudei o nome de `IContactService` para `ContactService` e a implementação passou a se chamar `DefaultContactService`.

```
package br.com.agenda.services;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import br.com.agenda.models.Contact;

public interface ContactService {

    public void save(Contact contact);

    public Contact update(Contact contact);

    public void remove(Contact contact);

    public Optional<Contact> find(int identifier);

    public List<Contact> listAll();
}
```

#### DefaultContactService.java

```
package br.com.agenda.services;

import static java.util.Objects.requireNonNull;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import br.com.agenda.daos.ContactDAO;
import br.com.agenda.models.Contact;

@Service
public final class DefaultContactService implements ContactService {

    @Autowired
    private ContactDAO contactDAO;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(Contact contact) {
        requireNonNull(contact, "contact cannot be null");
        contactDAO.save(contact);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Contact update(Contact contact) {
        requireNonNull(contact, "contact cannot be null");
        return contactDAO.update(contact);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void remove(Contact contact) {
        requireNonNull(contact, "contact cannot be null");
        contactDAO.remove(contact);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Contact> find(int identifier) {
        return contactDAO.find(identifier);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Contact> listAll() {
        return contactDAO.listAll();
    }
}
```

#### Contact.java

Mudei o relacionamento de entre `Contact` e `Phone` de `@ElementCollection` para `@OneToMany`:

```
package br.com.agenda.models;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

@Entity
@Table(name="tblContacts")
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="idContacts")
    private int id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name="nameContacts")
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name="emailContacts")
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @Valid
    private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addPhone(Phone phone) {
        phones.add(phone);
    }

    public List<Phone> getPhones() {
        return phones;
    }

    public void setPhones(List<Phone> phones) {
        this.phones = phones;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

#### Phone.java

```
package br.com.agenda.models;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tblPhones")
public class Phone {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="idPhones")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="dddPhones")
    private int ddd;

    @Column(name="numberPhones")
    private int number;

    public int getDdd() {
        return ddd;
    }

    public void setDdd(int ddd) {
        this.ddd = ddd;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }       
}
```

#### ContactController.java

```
package br.com.agenda.controllers;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import br.com.agenda.models.Contact;
import br.com.agenda.services.ContactService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/contact")
public class ContactController {

    @Autowired
    private ContactService contactService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/all", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView listContact() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("contact-list");
        modelAndView.addObject("contacts", contactService.listAll());
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

#### contact-list.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Contact List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <c:forEach var="contact" items="${contacts}">
            <label>${contact.name}</label><br />
        </c:forEach>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Certo entendi, mais creio eu que ainda vou continuar com o problema, pois o mesmo está vindo do return  do listAll() na camada DAO, não sei talvez a query do hibernate está incorreta.

Comment: @MarcosPaulo A `NullPointerException` ocorre **dentro** do método `listAll()`. A exceção é lançada porque se está tentando evocar o método  `createQuery` de um `EntityManager null` .

Comment: Fiz oque você mi falou porém o erro continua sendo retornado, testei a implementação e o erro é gerado somente no método listAll(), você não axa que a forma como estou listando todos os objetos estão errados não?

Comment: @MarcosPaulo Há sim um erro na sua query, ela deve usar o nome das classes e não das tabelas. Sua query deveria ser `SELECT DISTINCT(c) FROM Contact c JOIN FETCH c.phones`. Porém, se sua query estivesse sendo executada, apareceria na stack trace a exceção `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException`. Como essa exceção não ocorre, isso leva a crer que a sua query não é nem executada. O problema é antes. Coloque os arquivos de configuração do Hibernate/Spring por favor.

Comment: Editei o post com os 3 arquivos de configuração.

Comment: @MarcosPaulo Testei com os arquivos que você colocou e, aplicando as alterações que citei anteriormente, o programa funcionou e não lançou nenhuma exceção. A única mudança que tive que fazer foi mudar anotação da classe `AppWebConfiguration` de `@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses={IndexController.class, ContactDAO.class})` para `@ComponentScan(basePackages={"br.com.agenda"})` porque o Spring não estava encontrando algumas classes. Caso não funcione para você, me avise que edito minha resposta e coloco todas as classes que estão rodando comigo para você testar.

Comment: Felipe, por favor se puder colocar as classes, o meu continuo retornando a exception, já quebrei a cabeça e até hoje não consegui resolver.

Comment: @MarcosPaulo adicionei as classes.

Comment: Eu vi que a implementação do DAO juntamente com a do Service são bem idênticas, é realmente necessário ambas as duas ou poderia ser somente 1 camada?

Comment: Depende da complexidade do domínio. O código que coloquei é bem simples e a camada Service acaba sendo redundante e pode ser considerada desnecessária. Porém, é comum que ela tenha que consumir Web Services e conter a lógica necessária para interagir com múltiplas DAOs em relacionamentos mais complexos entre entidades. A DAO deve apenas servir para abstrair o acesso a unidade de persistência.

Comment: Entendi, no caso do service tipo ele teria a logica para persistir os usuários e os acessos referentes a eles, ai manipularia 2 DAOS.